# Google Sheets DGET function not matching on a case where data exists

Tags: google-sheets

In the following sheet

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xFtZJOQ1JbnyKTBrFx-P9H10XqAmYE8zEiP7aaFAVe4/edit?usp=sharing

in tab Sheet1 cell AB3 I am trying to link DGET to pull the timestamp from tab Pre-Installation matching on the complaint number column W. It shows no results despite the row having the value

Is there some aspect I am missing here. The function being used is

=DGET('Pre-Installation'!A:I,"Timestamp",{"Complaint Number"; W3})

Comment: Nothing is imported in your `Sheet1`.

Comment: hi we are trying to import the timestamp in Sheet 1 cell AB3 USING dget. This is returning no match when matching on complaint tag even though data is available in the pre-installation sheet

Comment: It should work. Please change permissions to your sheet. It is now read only

Comment: @marikamitsos permission updated. not working in this sheet. still shows no result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated answer** *(following OP's sharing the sheet)*

The formula does work as expected.

**Please make sure the headings match exactly.**

The problem lies in the fact that in your imported data, the heading is
`Complaint Number +1ExtraSpace` .
Notice the **extra empty space in the end**.

What you have in your `DGET` function is
`Complaint Number +NoExtraSpace`.
Since the data is imported, by changing the heading to `Complaint Number` without any extra space in the end, the formula works as expected.

**BEST PRACTICE**
When writing the formula, **always Copy+Paste the headers**, thus avoiding any mistakes

---

Original answer

**The formula does work as expected**.

```
=DGET('Pre-Installation'!A:I,"Timestamp",{"Complaint Number"; W3})
```

You do need though to format it as `Date time` from the menu.

[image]

Comment: hi @marikamitsos. permission is updated to allow editing. but in my sheet the query shows no result for dget as you can see in the sheet. is there something different between the sheets

Comment: Please check the added sheet `marikamitsos`. It works

Comment: Glad I could help :)